# make separat dataframes of list.files - R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, sas

Hi I have a list of SAS files;

```
filelist <- list.files('SASfilenames', full.names = TRUE)
```

Filelist contains 15 filepaths to 15 SAS files, and I want to make these as 15 separat dataframes. How can I do so?

Comment: How do you read a single SAS file?

Comment: a function called importSAS from a package called heaven

Answer (score 0):

With a vector of file paths, you can run a simple loop to read each file into a list, then reference the list by its position or name:

```
library(purrr)

filelist <- list.files('SASfilenames', full.names = TRUE)


sas_files <- map(filelist |> set_names(), ~{
    message("loading file: ", .x)
    haven::read_sas(.x)
})

sas_files[[1]]
sas_files[[2]]
sas_files[[3]]
sas_files[["path_to_file.sas"]]
```

Comment: thank you - when all my files run, can I call them a name so they will be separat datasets in my enviroment?

Comment: Sure, but I think you’ll have to do that manually, as I think there is no way to programatically create objects with different names, as lists are used for that